# python manage.py runserver: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, django, pypi

After running the command, the following displays :

```
Validating models...

0 errors found

Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'app.settings'
Development server is running at localhost:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x000000
00033BBD30>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\commands\runserver.py", line 111, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\servers
\basehttp.py", line 253, in run
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Any idea of what the issue is ?

I already tried uninstalling and installing again (setuptools, pypi, django, requests)

Comment: Do you have a `select.py` in your project maybe?

Comment: @Wessie: Great guess. Can't count how many times I have made that mistake...

Comment: Verified and I don't have a `select.py` in my project. I am still getting the error : ( I have no idea what is wrong with it

Comment: Can you post some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Flask app.

I realized I had created a script called "select.py", so I had to rename it and remove "select.pyc".